# What would you call the sound a flute makes?

Tags: expressions

All I can come up with is the adjective lilting.

Comment: Are you looking for a better adjective? If so, what's unsatisfactory about _lilting_? Or are you looking for a noun or something else?

Comment: There probably isn't anything in the same way a *drum* makes *drumming*, or a *whistle* makes *whistling/a whistle*. Most instruments don't have dedicated adjectives/nouns for their own particular sound. And if you just want *any* descriptive word, such as *lilting*, it's probably subjective/POB (it might also depend very much on *how* someone plays the flute).

Comment: It would help if you gave us a sample sentence with a gap where the word would fit. The extra context will help. For example are you referring to classical music? Folk music? Something else?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer you are looking for is:

> [***piping***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/piping) 2. (*Music*) b. The music produced by a pipe when played.
>
> [***pipe***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pipe) 5. (*Music*) a. A tubular wind instrument, such as a flute.

Comment: All 11 pipers are piping to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is "**tootle**" and "**tootle-too**".

> [tootle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tootle) *n.* **3.** the sound made by tooting on a flute or the like.
>
> [tootle-too](http://www.onomatopoeialist.com/tootle-too/) sound of a flute (“the ceremonial band” by James Reeves, in “Noisy poems” by Jill Bennett)

Comment: Classical and orchestral players would be insulted if you called it tootling. Let's get some more context.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "**trill**", which has a specific musical meaning, but is a technique often used by flautists.

Comment: *Trill* is only one of the ornaments available to flute playing; they are also available to a wide range of instruments, including the human voice. Your answer is akin to offering *glissando* or *tremolo* as a solution here.